# Add value in attribute field using arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I need to add values to an existing field in the attribute table. The values are to be determined by values in another field in the same attribute table. I am unable to define the values in another field in the script. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've not used Arc 10.1 cursors, but it's apparently even easier there.

In 10.0, there are a few ways to go about it, but here's a basic, beginner's approach:

```
# Create a cursor on a feature class
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(myFeatureClass)

# Loop through the rows in the attribute table
for row in cur:
    # The variable sqMiles will get the value from the column
    # named 'Area_Miles'
    sqMiles = row.getValue('Area_Miles')
    # Calculate how many acres
    acres = (sqMiles * 640)
    # Assign the acres to a column named 'Area_Acres'
    row.setValue('Area_Acres', acres)
    # Apply the change
    cur.updateRow(row)

    # The loop will then move on to the next row/feature
```

A simpler, condensed version:

```
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(myFeatureClass)

for row in cur:
    row.setValue('Area_Acres', row.getValue('Area_Miles') * 640)
    cur.updateRow(row)
```

See: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003m000000

Comment: Tom, please re-write ALL of ESRI's "Help Files" using the method you used in this answer.  Then more people will understand, and the world will be a happier place.

Comment: Tom, please follow @JasonMiller 's advice. And thank you VERY much for cracking this down for us. I considered myself illiterate, but now no more.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a few ways you can do this.

1. If the calculation is fairly simple, I would use the [Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000) tool. If you need to use the code_block parameter, I'd go with option #2 as it's not always easy getting the syntax correct in a script (or in the tool itself for that matter).
2. If you are interested in scripting more in the future, I'd strongly recommend using [cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001q000000). You can write the values from one field into a Python list and perform your calculations on each item in the list with a for loop and then write the list back to your new field.

I rarely use Calculate Field anymore as it's easier to script cursors for all but the simplest formulas.