# Add a field value to a polyline that's generated from an cursor.insertRow in Arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a feature class that is built using the calculated values along two lines. I am trying to add a new column with a value from each line but am not able to.

I have a list that looks like

```
['102382191', '102387203', 'fe3bd81d-4c9f-4134-b7fe-e3529d2d7749'],
['104750210', '104716195', 'fe886c2d-c0a4-42b5-9f5b-fcade3dda238']]
```

from this we get the three values

```
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(out_fd+"/Turn_Lines",
                           ["SHAPE@"])
for turn in turnNotAllowedList:
        fromUFI = turn[0]
        toUFI = turn[1]
        rUFI = turn [2]
```

We have an array which get us the positions along the line to use

```
streetDictA = {str(row[1]): row[0].positionAlongLine(0.5,True).firstPoint for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(
    out_fd+"/streets", ["SHAPE@","EdgeFID"])}
```

The feature to add is built using

```
array = arcpy.Array()
array.add(streetDictA[fromUFI])
array.add(streetDictB[toUFI])
#array.add(rUFI)
polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array,sr)
cursor.insertRow([polyline])
```

How do I get the table to include the rUFI value? so that it has 
[image]

I have tried `cursor.insertRow([polyline],r_UFI)` but I get

> TypeError: insertRow() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Do I need to insert the polyline and then separately add the new column and value [like this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64451/add-value-in-attribute-field-using-arcpy)?

an example line would have the following

```
>>> streetDictA[fromUFI]
<Point (150.7028015, -33.753457, #, #)>
>>> streetDictB[toUFI]
<Point (150.702866881, -33.7537085424, #, #)>
>>> rUFI
'00004e53-5700-4600-0000-0000245bdf33'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(out_fd+"/Turn_Lines", ["SHAPE@"])`

You already decided to only be able to insert one value: `SHAPE@` then you try to insert two: `[polyline]` and `r_UFI`

You need to include both when creating the cursor:

```
import os
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(os.path.join(out_fd,"Turn_Lines"), ["SHAPE@","somefieldname"])
```

And the field "somefieldname" need to be added to your feature class before you can insert values.

Comment: Great -As this fc is built using the array, how do I add the r_UFI column to hold the value?

Comment: [Add Field](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-field.htm): `arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=os.path.join(out_fd,"Turn_Lines"),...`

Comment: Sorry to be clear I have added the field as `arcpy.AddField_management(in_table="Turn_Lines", field_name="r_UID", field_type="TEXT", field_precision="", field_scale="", field_length="50", field_alias="", field_is_nullable="NULLABLE", field_is_required="NON_REQUIRED", field_domain="")`
but how do I add the value r_UFI in the cursor.insertRow?

Comment: Im not sure what you are doing with the shape, but something like `cursor.insertRow([polyline,r_UFI])` should work. insertRow wants a "A list or tuple of values". Look at the examples in the [help section](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm)